# Displaying/ editing labels for Mosaic plot in R with 4 variables?

Tags: r, mosaic-plot

I am working with the Arrests data in "effects", I am currently trying to create a mosaicplot to show the relationship between released,colour, employed, and citizen. When I create the plot I only have labels for released and color. I would like to have labels for citizen and employed, or at least C:Yes and C:No on the plot so it is more obvious what each yes and no is for.
Also I want to move the labels around some, like distance from the graph.

```
mosaicplot(~ colour + released + citizen + employed, data=Arrests, shade=T)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: The documentation tells us that `mosaic` in pkg:vcd will be more flexible. And to Katya, the Arrests data is in the package. For once, a first time poster has actually provided a MWE.

Comment: @42- Thank you! That worked a lot better. I am having some trouble with changing the direction, of the labels, I tried las but is there something special I have to do to get it to work? trying help(mosaic) and help(mosaicplot) has gotten me no where

Comment: `mosaic` is a grid based plotting function so 'las' (which works for base-graphics) would not succeed.  If you post modified code I can take a look. A quick look (as in actually reading the `?mosaic` help page) suggests you need to go to the `?labelings` help page and use the `rot_labels` argument.